# How to get contents of div tag using selenium (python)

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

[image: Html Code]

How would I get the contents of the div tag that I underlined? I have already tried copying and pasting the xpath, but it doesn't work when printing the contents of the div.

```
div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="sold_out_tag"]')
```

is another thing I've tried, but when I try typing `div.text`, it just prints empty spaces.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Add a debug statement where you use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` (note the plural, s) and print the count of the number of elements. My guess is that your locator isn't specific enough and you are finding more than one and the first one that is returned is empty. A link to the page would help.

Comment: I can't tell from your screenshot (which is another reason why screenshots are a bad idea) whether there are underscores between "sold out tag". Are there spaces or underscores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print `sold out` you can try the following line of code :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']/a//div[@class='sold_out_tag']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`div.text` should work or may be there are multiple div tag with the same class name.